# PayPal Plus: REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING

Tags: paypal, postman, paypal-sandbox

I followed the guide of PayPal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/get-started/

and made a request to `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token` to obtain an access token.

This works totally fine.

Now I want to do the following request: `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment`

(Selecting Bearer Auth in Postman, using the token I obtained in the request before)

Now I get the following error response:

```
{
    "name": "REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING",
    "message": "Access token does not have required scope",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
    "debug_id": "548db8d53cfde"
}
```

Yes, I configured my project to allow such things:

[App configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQauL.png)

I really appreciate any help.

EDITED:

Response from: `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token`

```
{
    "scope": "https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalhere https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture openid https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund https://uri.paypal.com/services/identity/activities https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/refund https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/.*/refund",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 30189
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no actual issue with your scopes, all are there.

It seems your payment request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment is incomplete

See here for an example guide for creating a payment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/#create-paypal-payment

Be sure to pass a transaction object with an amount, and any other required parameters

Comment: Actually the settings were right from the beginning but yes, I do use "grant=client_credentials", why?

Comment: I might see the problem. All of those scopes aren't prefixed with: "api.sandbox". But I'm using an sandbox app...

Comment: It's a problem with the payment request

Comment: Indeed. The documentation, at least for me, just implied that, I only need to specify "intent" and "payment_method". Thank you very much.

Do you know, where I can get the information of "debug_id"?